# Efficiently const_cast-ing a constant reference parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, reference, constants, const-cast

I have a member function which takes a constant reference parameter to another object. I want to const_cast this parameter in order to easily use it inside the member function. For this purpose, which of the following codes is better?:

```
void AClass::AMember(const BClass & _BObject)
{
    // FORM #1 - Cast as an object:
    BClass BObject = const_cast<BClass &>(_BObject);
    // ...
}

void AClass::AMember(const BClass & _BObject)
{
    // FORM #2 - Cast as a reference:
    BClass & BObject = const_cast<BClass &>(_BObject);
    // ...
}
```

Can you please compare these two forms? Which one is better in criteria of speed and memory usage?

Comment: May I ask what your purpose with this is? If you need to conform to an API that isn't `const` correct, it would be better to perform the cast at the call site to show why you're casting and minimize the potential for abuse.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first version makes a copy of the object.  The second version doesn't.  So the second version will be faster unless you want to make a copy.

By the way, all identifiers that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the compiler.  You should not be using variable names like `_BObject`.

Comment: It is usually safe to use variable names with a '_'
Normally compilers use the double underscore, but I often read this generalized rule of not using _

Comment: C++ standard, §17.4.3.1.2: “Each name that contains a double underscore (__) or begins with an underscore followed by an upper-
case letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use.”  Don't use reserved identifiers unless you're implementing the compiler or the standard library.

Comment: _variableName or _variable_name is then perfectly fine, and I've seen it used in several places with no problem at all.

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant to my answer.

Answer (score 11):

The first one doesn't make any sense as you cast away constness of `_BObject` to only later pass it as a constant reference to `BClass` constructor and create a copy, `BObject`. The second one does what it means - casts away the constness and keeps the reference to the original object. So if you ask me, the second one is better. Be aware though that `const_cast` is not always safe.